# EventHubTrigger is not working in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to build simple **azure functions v2** application that will contain two functions, one is triggered based on **TimerTrigger** and another that will be triggered by **EventHubTrigger**. Also I have IoC container configuration using Startup.cs class. TimerTrigger - works fine, but I have some troubles with EventHubTrigger.
Here is my setup. EventHubFunction:

```
namespace BgService
{
    public class MyFunctions
    {
        [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
        public async Task RunAsync([EventHubTrigger("myHubName", Connection = "hub")] string events, ILogger log)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "*****",

    "hub": "Endpoint=sb://***.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=***"
  }
}
```

My Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(BgService.Startup))]
namespace BgService
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {


        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
           // SomeConfiguration
        }
    }
```

When I run my azure function project I get a next error:

```
[19.07.2019 12:26:23] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'MyFunction'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs: Value cannot be null.
[19.07.2019 12:26:23] Parameter name: receiverConnectionString.
```

Used version of **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions** -> 1.0.29

And now the tricky part:
When I downgrade the version of **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions** to 1.0.25 without any modification in code -> it magically starts to work, BUT **Startup.Configure()** method is not called any more(in version 1.0.29 it is working).

Thanks for any assistance, spent a hours on troubleshooting this problem.

Comment: What version of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs are you using? And could you try appending the `EntityPath=<EventHubName>` to the connectionstring?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1299

You should as a workaround downgrade package Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs to 3.0.0